# Is passing data between directives, controllers, and services using $emit and $broadcast bad practice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I'm a beginning Angular developer and I was wondering if the way I've passed data between controllers is bad practice or not.

I'm creating a seatmap widget whereby you click on a seat and it will display data in another part of the App using a different controller.

1) I have a **directive** that incorporates dynamic templating. Based on the model being passed (from an ng-repeat), it will create an event listener like so:

```
if(scope.seat.isAvailable) {
  element.bind('click', function() {
    scope.$emit('clickedSeat', scope.seat);
  }
  element.append(seatAvailableTemplate);
}
```

2) In my **controller**, I have the following listening for the click:

```
$scope.$on('clickedSeat', function(event, seat) {
  seatSelectionService.broadcastSeatData(seat);
}
```

3) I have a **service** where I've passed in **$rootScope** which allows me to broadcast the data to a different controller:

```
var seatSelectionService = {};
seatSelectionService.broadcastSeatData = function(clickedSeat) {
  seatSelectionService.seatData = clickedSeat;
  $rootScope.$broadcast('seatSelected');
}
return seatSelectionService;
```

4) In the **other controller**, I have a listener which sets the $scope attribute, which renders {{selectedSeat}} in the view:

```
$scope.$on('seatSelected', function() {
  $scope.selectedSeat = seatSelectionService.seatData;
  $scope.apply();
}
```

Of course I have had to pass in **seatSelectionService** into both controllers for it to work.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is this way of passing data valid practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$broadcast` and `$emit` themselves aren't bad practice, but it does look like you've over complicated your app.

You can add *services* directly to *directives* - they can have controllers built into them that depend on the services.

So in your directive, add a controller that uses the seatSelectionService, something like:

```
seatSelectionService.setSeat( scope.seat )
```

Which cuts out one of the steps at least - your `setSeat` method would still want to do a `$broadcast` when it's done down to anything listening.

Directives can be really simple or really complex - they can simply be a quick way of outputting a repeated template, or a dynamic template with a controller and access to multiple services.

Something else you might want to look at is *promises* - I used to use $broadcast and $emit a lot more than I needed to, until I learnt how to use promises and `defer` properly

Comment: Thanks! Answered my question, learned something new, and pointed me to look into a different way of doing things. I would give you 3 checks if I could :P

Comment: Just passing the knowledge on. You have to pass it on now

Answer (score 2):

I would say less is more- if you can get rid of code do it- I would suggest you remove this in your controller unless you are doing something you are not showing, and put it in your directive, in step one:

```
$scope.$on('clickedSeat', function(event, seat) {
  seatSelectionService.broadcastSeatData(seat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response! Willshaw answered first though so I gave him the check. Again, appreciate it!